# NTLM Proxy Authentication not working in Python

Tags: python, proxy, ntlm

I am behind my college's ISA Proxy | Forefront Threat Management Gateway. The proxy uses NTLM Auth, so we are given credentials along with the proxy server ip and port. I have been trying a lot of Python modules like urllib,ullib2,urllib3, requests,requests-ntlm httlib and even cntlm and ntlm proxy. Nothing is working in my case. It's returning " 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront 
TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )" or any socket error. I even tried ntlmaps. It too didn't worked out. I know NTLM is already kind of depreciated. But still some of you guys may be working behind your corporate proxy with NTLM Auth. So Any work arounds? I want a pythonic code that works on both Windows and Linux that can communicate to internet through the intermediate upstream proxy.

Answer (score 0):

check out this article http://www.codemiller.com/blog/2011/05/28/overcoming-auth-pop-ups/ 
Maybe it will help - maybe it wont, but worth trying some of the solutions - as one of them worked for me in working around the glorious ntlm auth.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)? with http_proxy environment varible? if you wish i can post step by step guide to solve this problem permanently..

Comment: If you wish reputation, you should post the guide ;)